# Как выполнить WHERE-запрос к MS SQL, используя PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Я использую PHP 7.3 и библиотеку php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll для доступа к Microsoft SQL Server 14. Для удобства выполнения запросов в основном коде, я несколько лет использую код, который взял (по-моему) из какой-то версии OpenCart и адаптировал его для работы с MSSQL. Одна из основных функций - **query** - выглядит вот так:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    $result = false;

    try {
        if ($this->statement && $this->statement->execute($params)) {
            $data = array();

            while ($row = $this->statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            $result = new \stdClass();
            $result->row = (isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array());
            $result->rows = $data;
            $result->num_rows = $this->statement->rowCount();
        }
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' Error Code : ' . $e->getCode() . ' <br />' . $sql);
    }

    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        $result = new \stdClass();
        $result->row = array();
        $result->rows = array();
        $result->num_rows = 0;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Все это время функция исправно служила мне, но недавно я заметил, что она попросту игнорирует некоторые значения. Например, запрос:

```
$rs = $db->query("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Products");
```

прекрасно выполняется, в то время как запрос

```
$rs = $db->query("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Products WHERE IsSuppressed = 1");
```

не возвращает никаких результатов. То есть `num_rows = 0`.

Я пробовал играть с `bindParam` и `prepare`, но ничего не достигает желаемого результата: первая строчка исполняется, а там где появляется `WHERE` и явно указанное условие - запрос не возвращает результатов. Причем, я просто хочу понять как это работает на простом и прямолинейном примере с явным указанием параметра (hardcoded query). То есть пока мне нет дела до SQL injection - я просто хочу увидеть как мой запрос (№2) выполнится и вернет recordset. Что я делаю не так? Где мне почитать об особенностях таких запросов?

Существуют ли удобные надстройки (wrappers) в виде класса, которые позволяют обращаться из PHP к SQL Server, используя простейшие методы? Например:

- **query** - запрос с возвращением данных в виде dataset/recordset.
- **exec** - запрос без возвращения данных; простое исполнение DML-оператора на стороне сервера.
- **sp_query** - то же что и query, но только вызов хранимой процедуры.
- **sp_exec** - соответственно.

Comment: покажи как ты обращаешься к функции query (sql, params) и что передаешь в её аргументы

Comment: А зачем вы используете функцию rowCount() Согласно документации она возвращает количество строк только для insert/update/delete, а вот для select она не гарантирует возврат правильного результата (может зависеть от СУБД !). https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php  Используйте количество выбранных строк в data, раз вы их все выбираете

Comment: я не бум-бум в ms sql, но всё отлично работает https://phpize.online/?phpses=c723b9688b14fddc7b0a6773f6cb4ab9&sqlses=bcd9024bfeac33ede0b2656165c472eb&php_version=php7&sql_version=mssql2017 ddl таблицы для примера нагуглил https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6e93ad968540b766e99c88b083c5ebbb

Comment: @Mike не гарантируется для всех бд, но конкретно в ms sql 2017/2019 отлично возвращается, достаточно проверить эту функцию для его версии ms sql 2014.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, большое спасибо за пример. А могу я в PHP PDO вообще не использовать подготовку запроса с именованными/неименованными параметрами? Все что я хочу - это выполнить _конкретный_ запрос `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Products WHERE IsSuppressed = 1` То есть просто эту строку передать в функцию. Есть ли такая функциональность?

Comment: конечно, по ссылке выше просто замени :age на 40 и убери $params в execute()

Comment: @Jean-Claude, еще раз спасибо! То что, `execute()` можно вызывать без параметров - откровение для меня. Буду читать маны. Я пока еще новичок в PHP, но у меня все получилось.

Comment: Сами же написали, что `PDO::query` выполняет простой запрос без параметров. Используйте его без всяких prepare/execute.